# Rescuing third party REST API exception in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I am connecting to Docusign via their REST API. Currently, I'm rescuing all exceptions which I understand is not a good idea. I would like to rescue certain exceptions that are thrown by the API. When I receive an exception from the API right now it displays the following in console:

```
{"errorCode"=>"USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED", "message"=>"One or both of Username and Password are invalid."}
```

The formatting of their errors is:

```
(errorDetails.errorCode) and associated messages (errorDetails.message)
```

How can I rescue individual exceptions with the response they're sending back to me? My current code is:

```
def show

  begin
    client = DocusignRest::Client.new
    [Other API actions]
  rescue [Rescue USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED here]
    [log exception here]
  rescue => e
    [log exception here]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide multiple exception classes that you would like to rescue:

```
begin 
  client = DocusignRest::Client.new
  # do some stuff
rescue DocusignCrazyError, DocusignBreakingError, DocusignAnotherError => error
  # log exception
end
```

Comment: But how do I find out what the class name is. Going through their docs this is all I found: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/Error%20Code/Error%20Codes%20and%20Associated%20Messages.htm the only thing I am getting back is the json response.

Comment: And the ErrorCode is not in the JSON response or what?  Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: The error is being returned in the json response ({"errorCode"=>"USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"}) but I'm not sure what kind of logic to write in my begin rescue block to rescue that error? For example, I tried `rescue DocusignUserAuthenticationFailed` and it didn't work.

Comment: If its just in the JSON response, there is no error to rescue. Just parse the JSON with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Ahh ok- got it. That makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up.